# How to trigger the __cplusplus (C++) #ifdef?

Tags: c++, macros

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
// C++ code
#else
// C code
#endif
```

The structure is this.
My question is, how to actually trigger the `#ifdef` on?

I mean, in program? What code I write can turn `#ifdef` on?

For example, in this case.
is that

```
#define __cplusplus
```

will turn it on?

Comment: #ifdef only checks if some macro defines, say, __cplusplus, you can define them with compiler flags (in gcc) with -D, or in the program with the #define directive

Comment: @mikhailvs In this case, none of the examples you give cover this specific case. The compiler itself defines this flag, and so the user can expect this to be defined. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> "#define __cplusplus"
>
> will let it on?

Yes, it will "let it on".

`__cplusplus` should be automatically defined by C++ compiler. C++ uses different [name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) and the macro often used to make C headers compatible with C++:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

...

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Just to add more info: I tested further whether compiling with `gcc` but with both of `-lstdc++` and `-xc++` would do the trick to make `__cplusplus` defined, the result is not. Only way is to use C++ compiler.

Answer (score 16):

Just compile it with a C++ compiler and `__cplusplus` is defined automatically in that case.

Answer (score 13):

The C++ Standard enforces that `__cplusplus` will always be defined in C++ programs. The C Standard obviously does not. This means that the user need go to no effort to enable this machinery.

Comment: In fact, the C standard enforces that it will _not_ be defined. Bit of cooperation between the two committees.

Answer (score 10):

A C++ compiler defines this automatically.

Since this starts with two consecutive underscores, it is reserved. You are *not* allowed to define it yourself (i.e., attempting to do so gives undefined behavior).

Comment: I didn't know "Since this starts with two consecutive underscores, it is reserved.". Thanks.