# Is it possible to set g++ to follow C++11 ISO (-std=c++11) through #define?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, preprocessor-directive

I'm quite new to c++11 and I was wondering something...

I am using Code::Blocks and if I were to use `c++11` in this IDE, i had to go to compiler settings, and and Check "`Have g++ follow the C++11 ISO C++ language standard`"

Is there any workaround so I can set a single `.cpp` file to use `c++11` in the `#define` statement like this?

**Note: This is a single "Build" file, NOT a project**

**By setting the compile option while not in project, it'll set it to Global Compile option that I prefer to not happen**

*I know that you can customize the build option in Project Files that It'll set `c++11` for that project only*

```
#include <iostream>

#define -std c++11

int main(){

    #if __cplusplus==201402L
        std::cout << "C++14" << std::endl;
    #elif __cplusplus==201103L
        std::cout << "C++11" << std::endl;
    #else
        std::cout << "C++" << std::endl;
    #endif
    return 0;
}
```

What I have found:

Changing `#define __cplusplus 201103L` is NOT a good idea, because it don't set the compiler to compile as `c++11`

Comment: Setting only a single file is not a good idea.

Comment: What's wrong with adjusting compiler settings as you described?

Comment: Such a `#define` (or `#pragma`) wouldn't make sense. It might appear in the middle of source code. What to do in this case? Changing the standard of C++ in the middle of source code. (In edge cases, this can cause even slight changes of grammar.)

Comment: Changing `#define __cplusplus` is not only not a good idea, it's also illegal since that is a reserved identifier.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Because Global Compiler setting. If I were to compile a single file (Not project), and I set the compiler option, It's set to to global, and other files that I open will follow `c++1`

And also, When my friend copies the file, he'll get confused why the code gets error, because he don't understand how to set Compile Option

Comment: @Eljay I know. I've already tried it. Hence the question.

Comment: That's why one shouldn't use global compiler settings in CB when possible. Instead, create a project and change project-specific settings.

Comment: For your friend, you can use `#if`s (similar like you did) to wrap an [`#error`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error) to prevent he's using wrong settings. ;-)

Comment: @scheff - exactly what I was writing as my answer while you were commenting!

Comment: @TobySpeight Yepp, hence, the immediate upvote. ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I can see how it would be desirable for a source file to be self-documenting in this respect, this isn't possible.

The next best thing is to *test* conformance, as you've started to do:

```
#if __cplusplus < 201103L
#error This source must be compiled as C++11 or later
#endif
```

That ensures that compilation with a C++03 compiler will give a simple, understandable error message straight away.

Comment: I thought it had to be quoted but just found [Error directive](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor/error): _error_message can consist of several words **not necessarily in quotes**._

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to set g++ to follow C++11 ISO (`-std=c++11`) through `#define`?

**No**.

Neither C++ nor g++ have that feature. You might want to build simple one-file programs manually.

Answer (score 1):

**No**.

You shouldn't changing the `#define __cplusplus`. Read more in [How to trigger the __cplusplus (C++) #ifdef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6779663/how-to-trigger-the-cplusplus-c-ifdef), because `__cplusplus` should be automatically defined by C++ compiler. That's why changing the version is meant to be done via the compiler settings.

It doesn't make sense to have a file follow C++11, while the others would follow C++14, for example. The whole project should be compiled in a homogeneous way.

Notice that your code wouldn't compile: [Error: macro names must be identifiers using #ifdef 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426736/error-macro-names-must-be-identifiers-using-ifdef-0).

<sub>PS: What a nightmare it would be in terms of readability and maintenance if what you described was a good idea..</sub>

Comment: Imagine the possibilities!  `#define -std Pascal` ... `#define -std Ada` ... `#define -std C++1985` ... #define -std C++17` ... `#define -std VB.NET`.  What could go wnorg?

Comment: @Eljay it would keep things...spicy!

Comment: If it was a project, YES! It'll be a nightmare, but this is a single build file, so It shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: @SazeimSaheem I see your point, but in any case, it's not possible. You asked a good question, you deserved my upvote! Cheers